# Replicating curl POST with Invoke-RestMethod in PowerShell

Tags: rest, curl, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to replicate the following curl command in PowerShell:

```
linguist@qa:~ % curl -X POST -F text="Example lesson text" -F share_status=private \
                 -F title="Example Lesson Ttiel" -F collection=50510 \
                 -F image=@/home/lingq/Pictures/penguin.jpg \
                 -F tags=British -F tags=European
                 'https://www.lingq.com/api/languages/en/lessons/' -H 'Authorization: Token bd894eabcd4c0'
```

This is an API usage example from their page, I'm working with the assumption that it works. I don't know if it actually does, I don't have curl, and I don't want to have curl if possible.
I've been trying to recreate the command in PowerShell using the InvokeRestMethod function. So far what I got is this:

```
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Authorization","Token db3403c339fb4515c2940cccdcdcdbdcdbdcdbddc4cf453534453")
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post 'https://www.lingq.com/api/languages/ja/lessons/' -Headers $headers
```

I'm not even sure I'm adding the header with the token correctly, and I have no idea how to add the parameters that follow the -F in curl. I don't need image and tags, but the rest are crucial. Any ideas?

Edit: I have verified that the authentication token header works, by calling

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get 'https://www.lingq.com/api/profile/' -Headers $headers
```

with my token and getting my profile.
I've also found out what the ominous -F means in curl, it's form data. So now I'm trying to figure out how to send 4 form data values in one Invoke-RestMethod call.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53090534/7163041) that should help you out. If you are having trouble with what the `curl` switches mean, you don't have to install it to look up [its documentation](https://curl.se/).