# Translate curl commands into PowerShell

Tags: rest, powershell, curl, websense

Does anyone have experience with using the Websense API through PowerShell?  I need to translate the curl commands (which I have working) into Powershell so they can be scripted.  Anyone have any resources that would be useful?  Examples of curl commands that I need to translate are below:

**Start a new transaction:**

```
curl -k -u <username>:<password> -X POST https://<ps_ip_address>:<port>/api/web/v1/categories/start
```

**Add an API-managed category (all data in the HTTPS request):**

```
curl -k -u <username>:<password> -X POST https://<ps_ip_address>:<port>/api/web/v1/categories -d "{\"Transaction ID\":\"<transaction_ID_string>\",\"Categories\": [ {\"Category Name\": \"<name_string>\",\"Category Description\":\"<description_string>\",\"Parent\": <numeric_category_ID>}]}"
```

**Add a URL (all data in the HTTPS request):**

```
curl -k -u <username>:<password> -X POST https://<ps_ip_address>:<port>/api/web/v1/categories/urls -d "{\"Transaction ID\": \"<transaction_ID_string>\",\"Category ID\": <numeric_ID>,\"URLs\":[\"https://www.new_url.com/\"]}" --cacert PolApiServer.crt
```

**Commit the transaction:**

```
curl -k -u <username>:<password> -X POST https://<ps_ip_address>:<port>/api/web/v1/categories/commit?TransactionID="<id_string>"
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to write the interpreter for you but it is most certainly possible...or you could just run `curl.exe` from PowerShell (obviously, you'll need to install `curl.exe` on the machine you are using to run the curl commands from PowerShell)..

Look into `Invoke-WebRequest` or `Invoke-RestMethod` - both of those functions exhibit curl-like-behavior.

Edit:

So, the `curl` command in PowerShell is nothing more than an alias for `Invoke-WebRequest` .. run this: `Get-Alias -Definition Invoke-WebRequest` and review the output. Each parameter in `Invoke-WebRequest` matches up to a `curl` switch. All you have to do is review the `curl` documentation, and match their params up to `Invoke-WebRequest` params. A lot of what you're asking depends upon the API/site you are sending your HTTP request to (both `curl` and `Invoke-WebRequest` send HTTP requests).. For example, authenticating to an API/site.. if the site uses Basic Auth you would do something like this in PowerShell:

`Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri "https://<ps_ip_address>:<port>/api/web/v1/categories/start" -Headers @{"Authorization" = "Basic %your_encoded_credentials_here%" }`

.. The `curl -X` switch represents the HTTP method.. the `Invoke-WebRequest -Method` parameter serves the same purpose.. It sounds like you really just need to read up on `Invoke-WebRequest` or `Invoke-RestMethod` - the only difference in the two is the return they give you.

I think your confusion on how to differentiate, and ultimately interpret, `curl` to `Invoke-WebRequest`, has to do with the fact that you seem to be fresh into HTTP requests. Both of those commands send HTTP Requests - they just use different switches - if you learn how each command handles HTTP requests, you can interpret from `curl` to `Invoke-WebRequest`..

More here: [Invoke-WebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6) and [Invoke-RestMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-6)

There are also a TON of examples on how to interpret `curl` to `Invoke-WebRequest`/`Powershell` on this site alone.. you just need to brush up on HTTP requests and how `curl` handles them and the differences in how `Invoke-WebRequest` handles them.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few ways to do so.
1. download curl.exe and point a variable to it then pass the command to it

```
$curlExe = "C:\download\curl-7.59.0\src\curl.exe"
& $curlExe -i -k -X POST -d '"{\"groupId\": xxxx}"' "https://site/site?access_token=zzzzzz" -s
```

Another would be

```
 Invoke-RestMethod -uri https://site Get -Headers @{"x-api-key" = "mykey"} -ContentType "application/vnd.api+json" -Credential $adminCredential
```

I hope this help

Comment: This is helpful.  Translating the commands successfully into that format is my stumbling block presently.  I may need to update my question with current approach using the Invoke-RestMethod.  I am doing more testing and will either mark as answer or update my question with more detail.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could just translate into PowerShell syntax using [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-3.0TransactionID=%22%3Cid_string%3E%22).

```
PS> curl.exe '-k', 
 '-u', '<username>:<password>', 
 '-X', 'POST ', 
 'https://<ps_ip_address>:<port>/api/web/v1/categories/start'

PS> curl.exe '-k', 
 '-u', '<username>:<password>', 
 '-X', 'POST ', 
 'https://<ps_ip_address>:<port>/api/web/v1/categories',
 '-d', "{\"Transaction ID\":\"<transaction_ID_string>\",\"Categories\": [ {\"Category Name\": \"<name_string>\",\"Category Description\":\"<description_string>\",\"Parent\": <numeric_category_ID>}]}"

PS> curl.exe '-k', 
 '-u', '<username>:<password>', 
 '-X', 'POST ', 
 'https://<ps_ip_address>:<port>/api/web/v1/categories/commit?TransactionID="<id_string>"'
```

This command will call curl.exe from windows OS.
To know where this file just run

```
PS> Get-Command curl.exe
```

Comment: The JSON in your second example doesn't have correctly escaped double quotes for Powershell.

Comment: Curl in powershell having error:
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Documents> curl -X POST 'https://api.datadoghq.com/api/v1/dashboard' -H 'Accept: applica
son' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'DD-API-KEY: abc' -H 'DD-APPLICATION-KEY:
x’yz -d '@5052-dash.json'

Comment: Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot bind parameter 'Headers'. Cannot convert the "Accept: application/json" value of type
"System.String" to type "System.Collections.IDictionary".
At line:1 char:62
+ ... datadoghq.com/api/v1/dashboard' -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Con ...
+                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand